# VBA - add series depending on whether value in Column A has changed

Tags: vba, excel, highcharts, series

I have some data that looks like this...

```
Area Name   x value y value sum mia3ever    proportion  Postcode
London  0.71926819  0.194887721 257 12% TW13
London  0.249070388 0.678239918 153 7%  TW13
London  0.895600342 0.50096083  102 5%  TW13
London  0.226127681 0.286161753 32  2%  TW13
London  0.063482651 0.997888216 56  3%  TW13
London  0.559486828 0.3184387   44  2%  TW13
London  0.505436766 0.627708014 32  2%  TW13
London  0.51053101  0.90729441  21  1%  TW13
London  0.793446485 0.429025666 13  1%  TW13
London  0.984280399 0.961682652 7   0%  TW13
Swindon 0.40981356  0.89159907  321 15% SN3
Swindon 0.476922958 0.877030395 221 11% SN3
Swindon 0.054196462 0.630455049 128 6%  SN3
Swindon 0.50651053  0.250699362 194 9%  SN3
Swindon 0.765687797 0.291577129 126 6%  SN3
Swindon 0.349227537 0.642574308 23  1%  SN3
Birmingham  0.061425423 0.307267677 176 8%  B1
Birmingham  0.055064149 0.00827374  111 5%  B1
Birmingham  0.044373053 0.978586414 66  3%  B1
```

So far, my code looks like this...

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeChart()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim aRng As Range
Dim seriescheck As Range

Set aRng = Selection.CurrentRegion
    LastRow = aRng.End(xlDown).Row
    LastColumn = aRng.End(xlToRight).Column
        msg = MsgBox("Last Row: " & LastRow & ", Last Column: " & LastColumn)
Set aRng = aRng.offset(1, 0).Resize(aRng.Rows.Count - 1)
Set seriescheck = aRng.offset(1, 0).Resize(aRng.Rows.Count - 1, 1)

seriescheck.Select

For Each cell In seriescheck
If cell.value <> cell.offset(1, 0).value Then
    MsgBox ("Row: " & cell.Row)
End If

Next

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if you can see the image since I'm a new user, but I'll describe it anyway. It's postcode data, and column A has region names (eg London, Swindon, Birmingham). I need this code to add each region as a new series to a scatter chart.

So far I've figured out how to identify the end of each series, but I now need to add these to a chart object and get the code to end when it gets to the last row. I'm new to VBA and trying to a get grips with it, could anyone help at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code slightly, and added code that will add your data to a chart.

I wasn't sure exactly which part of the data you were looking to plot, so I've assumed that you want to do a scatter plot of the X-val / Y-val columns, with AreaName as the series name.

You'll need to add a blank scatter chart to your worksheet, and update the "Set cht = ...." line below to reference this.

Hope this is helpful, good luck finishing it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeChart()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim aRng As Range
Dim seriescheck As Range

    Set aRng = Selection.CurrentRegion
    Set aRng = aRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(aRng.Rows.Count - 1)
    Set seriescheck = aRng.Resize(aRng.Rows.Count, 1)

    Dim cht As Chart, seriesName As String, seriesData As Range

    'Set reference to chart: need to update this to match the location and name of the chart you create
    Set cht = Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    'Clear any series currently on the chart
    Call ClearChartSeries(cht)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long, cnt As Long

    'Loop through, find series data and add to chart
    startRow = 1: cnt = 0
    For Each cell In seriescheck
        cnt = cnt + 1
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            endRow = startRow + cnt - 1
            Set seriesData = aRng.Offset(startRow - 1, 1).Resize(endRow - startRow + 1, 2)
            seriesName = cell.Value
            Call AddChartSeries(cht, seriesName, seriesData)
            startRow = endRow + 1: cnt = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub


'Expecting two columns: date and index values
'Assumes x and y values are next to each other
Public Function AddChartSeries(cht As Chart, seriesName As String, rngData As Range)

    'Set data references
    Dim xAddress As String, yAddress As String
    xAddress = rngData.Parent.Name & "!" & rngData.Resize(rngData.Rows.Count, 1).Address
    yAddress = rngData.Parent.Name & "!" & rngData.Resize(rngData.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1).Address

    'Add a new series to the chart with these data references
    Dim seriesCnt As Long
    seriesCnt = cht.SeriesCollection.Count

    cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    cht.SeriesCollection(seriesCnt + 1).Name = seriesName
    cht.SeriesCollection(seriesCnt + 1).XValues = xAddress
    cht.SeriesCollection(seriesCnt + 1).Values = yAddress

End Function

'Removes all series from a chart
'Used to clear charts before adding new data
Public Sub ClearChartSeries(cht As Chart)

    Dim s As Series

    'Flush all existing series
    For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
        s.Delete
    Next s

End Sub
```